# Time outs with selenium, dynamics and ie driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm

So im using C# selenium to automate CRM Dynamics

Being and MS product it has issues with FF and Chrome so i have to run it in IE (And thus the IEDriver server)

Now performance is bad anyway, with locators failing to connect, but when stepped through in debug it all works so its a timing issue

Tried webdriverwait and that did nothing
I put a 500ms wait in the Driver call and this improves things (the webdriver is moving to quick for the browser it seems) but it still falls over.
I even put a thread.sleep(1000) on some slow loading pages and that helps but on the whole it still fails 30% of the time.

Anyone got any ideas how i can make this all more reliable?

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverContext.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)); 
DriverContext.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500); 
DriverContext.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(DriverContext.Driver.‌​WindowHandles.Last()‌​); 
DriverContext.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500); wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSel‌​ector("#crmGrid_quic‌​kFindContainer")));
```

The issue isnt my code i know that works as its all fine when i step thru in debug, im more interested if anyone has tried to automate CRM before and knows a way to get around the poor performance of the app itself especially when coupled with the iedriverserver for webdriver

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Can you update the actual question with your code block?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implicit wait?

**Implicit wait for 10 seconds,change as per your requirement.**

> driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is actually an issue with slow loading sites faced by most automation testers.Try introducing a wait till page gets loaded using explicit wait on some specific element in page which you know will be loaded last in that page may be it will help.But the downside,is the more waits you introduce in your tests,the slower your test execution gets :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/microsoft/easyrepro
Guys did really great job building framework on top of CRM and Selenium.
Haven't tried it with IE but worked like a charm for FF and Chrome.